# Prove that if $z_n\to1$ and $(z_n-1)w_n\to\lambda$ then $(z_n)^{w_n}\to e^\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Knowing that $(z_n),(w_n)$ are sequences in $\mathbb C$, where $z_n\not=0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and $\lim {z_n}=1$. Assuming we know that $\lim ({z_n-1}){w_n}=\lambda$, how can we prove that $\lim ({z_n}^{w_n})=e^\lambda$ ?

Comment: Personal input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Note that

$$\log(z)=(z-1)+O(z-1)^2$$

and that $z^w=e^{w\log(z)}$